# ExtJS 5.0 - Calling un or removeEventListener while in listener?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Some of our legacy code creates listeners with `on` and anonymous functions. These listeners have a finite lifespan.

Code is something like this:

```
me.getEl().on(someCondition()? 'mousedown': 'touchstart',
    function(event) {
        if (someOtherCondition()) {
            destroyStuff();
            // We don't need this listener any more!
            // ***
        }
    }
);
```

Checking the resource usage as the application runs, these zombie listeners accumulate and, especially the mouseover ones, use up a lot of resources and cycles.

Is there a way to use `un` or `removeEventListener` below the `// ***` comment and remove the listener? Say something along these lines:

```
event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, /* reference this anonymous function? */);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple options.

- `on` takes an `options` parameter that may contain `single:true` if it should only be executed once. I think this would not work for your example because the listener can be called multiple times, but possibly for some of your use cases that do not have a condition.
- You can use [`mon`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-mon) with `destroyable: true` to create destroyable listeners. These listeners can be removed using [`mun`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-mun).

Comment: `mon` is deprecated in ExtJS5 - just use 'on'. Which, as you say, can take the `destroyable: true` parameter to return a handler to remove the listener.

Comment: Which makes no sense, because normally you would deprecate things that are removed from the source in a later version. In 6.0.1, `mon` isn't deprecated anymore, at least not according to the docs.

Comment: Thank you, I used `single: true` for those cases for which it applied. The others, put in a TODO for someone else to do it!

Comment: Ah. They "undeprecated" it. You need `mon/addManagedListener` if the scope instance for the event handler in `on/addListener` isn't itself Observable; if the scope instance is Observable it registers itself to be removed on destruction.